# Angular 2 - Off-clicking a component fails

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Using Angular 2, I have a component that has a small popup `<div>`. Off-clicking will dismiss the popup (i.e. clicking anywhere in the document except on the popup will dismiss it). I use `HostListener` to achieve the effect.

This works as expected when there are no interior elements. However, if the popup has an interior element (e.g. `<div class="popup"><p>Inside</p></div>`) clicking on the popup will dismiss it. This is not the desired behavior.

This code works as expected:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h4 class="example" (click)="showPopup = true">
      Click to show popup that works as expected
    </h4>

    <div *ngIf="showPopup" class="example popup">
      Click anywhere besides here to dismiss me
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  public showPopup = false;

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) showThePopup(e: Event) {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains('example')) {
      this.showPopup = false;
    }
  }
}
```

However, changing the template in this way will fail:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: ` 
    <h4 class="example" (click)="showPopup = true">
      Click to show popup that work incorrectly
    </h4>

    <div *ngIf="showPopup" class="example popup">
      <p>Clicking here will dismiss me, which should not happen</p>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

What coding approach would make the code work correctly?

Working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7viqp6bR8LesM7lCsNQW?p=preview

Comment: `p` doesn't have `exemple` class so clicking on it will dismiss the popup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you separate the popup into a different component, it will save you a lot of hassle by not trying to figure out if any parent of the clicked element has the  popup class.

Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CZVs0niwQBUAHHgUJU2Z?p=preview) showing the concept

---

**Explanation**

When the popup is in a different component, you can gain access to the native element of the whole component using [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html), then check whether it contains the target of the click event.

We use `mousedown` so that it runs before a `(click)` event is fired.

```
@HostListener('document:mousedown', ['$event']) showThePopup(e: Event) {
    if(!this._eref.nativeElement.contains(e.target)){
        this.showPopup = false;
    }
}
```

You expose the variable `_eref` by adding the definition to your constructor:

```
constructor(private _eref: ElementRef) { }
```

In your parent component you can take advantage of [local variables](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-local-var) and `<ng-content>` to display the popup:

*app.html*

```
<h4 class="example" (click)="mypopup.show()">
  Click to show popup that works as expected
</h4>

<popup #mypopup>
  <div class="inside"><p>This is a Popup</p></div>
</popup>
```

*popup html*

```
<div *ngIf="showPopup" class="example popup">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Comment: you're missing a parenthesis after e.target

Comment: oops, fixed it now. Thanks!